# Why does FFmpeg trim my converted GIF?

Tags: ffmpeg

I pad my MP4 file then convert it to a GIF but why does FFmpeg trim the gif to a shorter video?

```
ffmpeg -i Media1.mp4 -f lavfi -i anullsrc -c:v copy -af apad -t 5.83 Media1extended.mp4
ffmpeg -i Media1extended.mp4 -vf "split[s0][s1];[s0]palettegen[p];[s1][p]paletteuse" -loop 0 Media1extended.gif
```

How do I make it not trim? e.g. a command `-autotrim 0`

EDIT: This is my command it did not work

```
ffmpeg -i Media1.mp4 -vf tpad=stop_mode=clone:stop_duration=5.83 Media1extended.mp4
ffmpeg -i Media1extended.mp4 -vf "split[s0][s1];[s0]palettegen[p];[s1][p]paletteuse;tpad=stop_mode=clone:stop_duration=5.83" -loop 0 Media1extended.gif

Simple filtergraph 'split[s0][s1];[s0]palettegen[p];[s1][p]paletteuse;tpad=stop_mode=clone:stop_duration=5.83' was expected to have exactly 1 input and 1 output. However, it had >1 input(s) and >1 output(s). Please adjust, or use a complex filtergraph (-filter_complex) instead.
Error reinitializing filters!
Failed to inject frame into filter network: Invalid argument
Error while processing the decoded data for stream #0:0
```

EDIT: This worked

```
ffmpeg -i Media1.mp4 -vf tpad=stop_mode=clone:stop_duration=5.83 Media1extended.mp4
ffmpeg -i Media1extended.mp4 -vf "split[s0][s1];[s0]palettegen[p];[s1][p]paletteuse" -t 5.83 -loop 0 Media1extended.gif
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your first command, only the audio gets padded to 5.83 seconds. If the source file `Media1.mp4`'s video stream is shorter, it will remain the same length since you're using `-c:v copy`.

To extend the video stream length, without re-encoding, you can loop the video stream in the first command i.e. `-stream_loop -1 -i Media1.mp4`. If you wish to hold the last frame, then use the tpad filter with clone mode after paletteuse and also add `-t 5.83`.